# PHP Comment System using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

I am developing a website using laravel PHP and trying to do a comment system using the following structure:

```
- Comment 1 (id = 1)
 -- Reply 1 (id = 2) (parent_id = 1)
  --- Reply 2.1 (id = 3) (parent_id = 2)
 -- Reply 2 (id = 4) (parent_id = 1)
```

I am wondering how would I do a foreach to cover that? Since i don't know how many child comments a comment will have.

Comment: Put comments and replies in seperate tables. In the reply table link a reply to a comment using the comment->id as a foreign key called something like `comment_id`

Comment: Yes. That's how i've done it. But I meant, how can I know how many childs each comment will have to do the foreach. @RiggsFolly

Comment: You either go recursivly thourgh the elements or your add another foreign key to the replies which refer to the actual comment (always) - then you can basiaclly select everything pointing to the comment and then organize it based on the parents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Table Like:

+------------+-----------+---------+
| comment_id | parent_id | comment |
+------------+-----------+---------+
|          1 |         0 | test    |
|          2 |         1 | test1   |
|          3 |         0 | test2   |
|          4 |         0 | test3   |
|          5 |         1 | test4   |
|          6 |         2 | test4   |
|          7 |         4 | test5   |
|          8 |         5 | test6   |
|          9 |         6 | test7   |
|         10 |         4 | test8   |
|         11 |         3 | test9   |
+------------+-----------+---------+


Get first level parent:

$comments = Comment::where('parent_id', '0')->orderBy('comment_id', 'asc')->get();

$result = array();
foreach($comments as $comment){
    $list = array();
    $list = array_merge($list, [['comment_id' => $comment->comment_id, 'parent_id' => $comment->parent_id, 'comment' => $comment->comment]]);
    $result = array_merge($result, $this->get_child_comment($comment->comment_id,0, $list));
}


function get_child_comment($pid,$level,$list=array()) {
        $sub_comments = Comment::where('parent_id','=',$pid)->where('comment_id','!=',$pid)->orderBy('comment_id', 'asc')->get();        
        foreach($sub_comments as $sub_comment){
            $space="&nbsp;"; sigm='-';
            for($j=0; $j<=$level; $j++)
            {
                $space .=$space;
            }
            for($j=0; $j<=$level; $j++)
            {
                $space .= $sigm;
            }
            $sub_comment->comment = html_entity_decode($space, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8").' '.$sub_comment->comment;

            $list = array_merge($list, array(['comment_id' => $sub_comment->comment_id, 'parent_id' => $sub_comment->parent_id, 'comment' => $sub_comment->comment]));

            $list = $this->get_child_comment($sub_comment->comment_id, $level+1, $list);
        }
       return $list;
    }
}


return get array.simple print using foreach:
foreach($result as $val) {
    echo $val['comment'].'<br>';
}

Output:

test

  - test1

    -- test4

        --- test7

  - test4

    -- test6

test2

  - test9

test3

  - test5

  - test8
```

Comment: But one doubt here how to store parent id

Comment: Parent comment id.

Comment: yeah stored but i did not get the exact result like you displayed in output

Comment: Hi, can I ask about this answer? where I should put `function get_child_comment` ? because if I put it inside my `public function ShowComment`, I got an error `Method [get_child_comment] does not exist.` But when I put it outside, I got no error, but it is just flat, no space/tab to make a differences between parent and child. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I *wouldn’t* store comments and replies in a separate table as they’re both comment entities at the end of the day. Simply have a `parent_id` column in your `comments` table, and you can fetch both comments and replies in one database query as opposed to two.

I assume you also have a foreign key linking a comment to something like a post. You can then fetch all comments for that post ID:

```
$comments = Comment::latest()->where('post_id', '=', $post->id)->get();
```

Then sort them based on their `parent_id` value:

```
$comments = $comments->keyBy('parent_id');
```

You can then iterate over them in your Blade template like this and every iterate, check if there are comments with that comment’s ID as its parent ID:

```
<!-- Kick-start the loop -->
@foreach($comments[0] as $comment)
    @include('partials.comment')
@endforeach
```

The content of **partials/comment.blade.php**

```
<blockquote class="comment">
    <p class="comment-body">{{ $comment->body }}</p>
    <footer>
        <span class="comment-author">{{ $comment->user->name }}</span>,
        <time class="comment-date" pubdate="pubdate">{{ $comment->created_at }}</time>
    </footer>
</blockquote>

@if(isset($comments[$comment['id']])
    @each('partials.comment', $comments[$comment['id'], 'comment')
@endif
```

Comment: i don't know what is wrong but it's giving me that: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/blogando/resources/views/partials/comment.blade.php)

Comment: @dante Because you’ll need to amend it to use your model’s actual attributes and not copy-and-paste my answer.

Comment: my model is using the exact names as you used.. on comment table id, body, on_post (post_id), created_at, updated_at ..

Comment: @dante What about `$comment->user`?

Comment: I am not using.. I am using only the $comment->body to test

Answer (score 0):

You can represent comments in following structure:

```
$comments = [
    (object)[
        'id' => 1,
        'text' => 'Comment 1',
        'children' => [
            (object)[
                'id' => 2,
                'text' => 'Reply 1',
                'children' => [
                    (object)[
                        'id' => 2,
                        'text' => 'Reply 1.1'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            (object)[
                'id' => 4,
                'text' => 'Reply 2',
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

And print them using recursive function like this:

```
function printComments($comments, $prefix = '-') {
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        echo $prefix.$comment->text.'<br>';
        isset($comment->children) && printComments($comment->children, $prefix.'-');
    }
}
```

Or calling view recursively in case of Laravel:

> @include('comments.view.path') inside of
>   @include('comments.view.path')

For convinient retrieving of comments in the represented structure and generally for working with tree structure I suggest using [nested set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) and [etrepat/baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) for Laravel which has **toHierarchy()** method.