# Adding a space/tab to make a differences between parent comment and child comment in PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, function, for-loop, foreach

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I have a page which contain a 'comment' from the users and it can be replied by another user.  My case is same like in [this stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012375/php-comment-system-using-laravel). I am following its correct answer. But mine is still not quite working. The child comments doesn't have a space/tab, so the differences between parent comments and child comments cannot be seen like the image below. Do you know why and how to fix this?

This is my database design :
[image] 

This Code below is in my controller:

```
public function ViewLead(Request $request)
{ 
$led_code = $request->LED_CODE;

$leads = Leads::leftjoin('CONTACT', 'LEADS.LED_SOURCE', '=', 'CONTACT.CON_CODE')->leftJoin('CLIENT', 'CONTACT.CON_CLIENTCODE', '=', 'CLIENT.CLI_CLIENTCODE')->where('LED_CODE', $led_code)->get();

$comments = Comments::where('COM_LEADS', $led_code)->where('COM_PARENTCODE', '0')->orderBy('COM_CODE', 'asc')->get();

$result = array();
foreach($comments as $comment){
    $list = array();
    $list = array_merge($list, [['COM_CODE' => $comment->COM_CODE, 'COM_PARENTCODE' => $comment->COM_PARENTCODE, 'COM_COMMENT' => $comment->COM_COMMENT, 'COM_NAME' => $comment->COM_NAME, 'COM_USERNAME' => $comment->COM_USERNAME, 'COM_CREATEDDATE' => $comment->COM_CREATEDDATE, 'COM_LIKE' => $comment->COM_LIKE, 'COM_LEADS' => $comment->COM_LEADS]]);
    $result = array_merge($result, $this->get_child_comment($comment->COM_CODE,0, $list));
}

$getdata = ['result'=>$result, 'leads'=>$leads];

return view('lead_view', $getdata);
}

function get_child_comment($pid,$level,$list=array()) {
$sub_comments = Comments::where('COM_PARENTCODE','=',$pid)->where('COM_CODE','!=',$pid)->orderBy('COM_CODE', 'asc')->get();     
foreach($sub_comments as $sub_comment){
    $space="&nbsp;"; $sigm='-';
    for($j=0; $j<=$level; $j++)
    {
        $space .=$space;
    }
    for($j=0; $j<=$level; $j++)
    {
        $space .= $sigm;
    }
    $sub_comment->comment = html_entity_decode($space, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8").' '.$sub_comment->comment;

    $list = array_merge($list, array(['COM_CODE' => $sub_comment->COM_CODE, 'COM_PARENTCODE' => $sub_comment->COM_PARENTCODE, 'COM_COMMENT' => $sub_comment->COM_COMMENT, 'COM_NAME' => $sub_comment->COM_NAME, 'COM_USERNAME' => $sub_comment->COM_USERNAME, 'COM_CREATEDDATE' => $sub_comment->COM_CREATEDDATE, 'COM_LIKE' => $sub_comment->COM_LIKE, 'COM_LIKE' => $sub_comment->COM_LIKE, 'COM_LEADS' => $sub_comment->COM_LEADS]));

    $list = $this->get_child_comment($sub_comment->COM_CODE, $level+1, $list);
}
return $list;
}
```

And this one is in my blade view:

```
@foreach($result as $getData)
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>{{ $getData['COM_NAME'] }}</b> <font color="grey">({{ date("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime($getData['COM_CREATEDDATE'])) }})</font><br>{{ $getData['COM_COMMENT'] }}<br><br>

  <form action="{{ url('AddLike') }}" method="POST">

    <font color="blue"> {{ $getData['COM_LIKE'] }}</font> <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-id="{{ $getData['COM_LEADS'] }}"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></button>&nbsp&nbsp
    <a onclick="$('.details{{ $getData['COM_CODE'] }}').slideToggle(function(){$('#more').html($('.details{{ $getData['COM_CODE'] }}').is(':visible'));});"><label>Reply</label></a><br>

  </form>
  <form action="{{ url('AddCommentReply') }}" method="POST">
    <div class="details{{ $getData['COM_CODE'] }}" style="display:none">
      <br><textarea class="form-control edit" id="" name="com_comment" style="width:90%"  placeholder="Type a your reply.." required></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

[image]

Comment: Check your CSS.

Comment: Do you know where I should put the class of parents and childs? on my blade view in `<td>` ? or somewhere in my controller? I'm confuse